# Django Crispy Forms: Set rows for Text Area

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

When creating a Form with `FormHelper()`, the text areas of my form (for `TextField`s) are too big: They are set to 10 rows. I'd like to set the number of rows. How can I do that?

My code:

#### `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Spam(models.Model).
    ham = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=False, default='Some ham')
    eggs = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False, default='', verbose_name="Lots of eggs")
```

#### `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispyy_forms.layout import (Layout, Row, Column)

from .models import Spam

class SpamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Spam
        fields = ('ham', 'eggs')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(Column('ham', css_class='form-group col-12')),
            Row(Column('eggs', css_class='form-group col-12')),
            # HERE: How can I set the rows for the text area widget?
        )
```

#### Resulting HTML:

```html
<!-- (ommited for brevity)  -->
<div  class="form-row " > 
  <div class="form_group col-12"  rows="2">
    <div id="div_id_eggs" class="form-group">
      <label for="eggs" class="">Lots of eggs</label> 
      <div class=""> 
          <textarea name="eggs" cols="40" rows="10" class="textarea form-control" id="eggs"></textarea> 
          <!--                            ^^^^^^^^
          <!--                            THIS is what I'd like to change to "2" -->
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
<!-- (ommited for brevity)  -->
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to alter the attributes for the `TextArea` widget that your `eggs` field is using.

```
class SpamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # no changes here
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # No changes to your existing code, just add this:
        self.fields['eggs'].widget.attrs = {'rows': 2}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can "override" the rows directly with crispy forms by passing rows in:

```
Row(Column('eggs', rows='2', css_class='form-group col-12')),
```

or with field:

```
Field('eggs', rows='2')
```

Comment: Using the `rows` kwarg with `Column` has no effect for me with Django 3.1.7 and Crispy Forms 1.11.2 - the only combination that works is `Field('eggs', rows=1)`. Note I'm also passing rows as an integer instead of a string. Is there a reason I should use Crispy's `Column` over `Field`?

Answer (score 2):

There are [many ways](https://www.thecodeteacher.com/question/92877/How-can-i-set-the-size-of-rows-,-columns-in-textField-in-Django-Models) to achieve this, but you can try with django widgets.

```py
text = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows": 7, "cols": 40}),
        label="Custom field label.",
    )
```

And then call your field by name in crispy forms Layout.